# How to select() elements background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write function that will select elements color on click and copy it to clipboard.

My function looks like this:

```
$(".color").click( function () {
  color = getComputedStyle(this).backgroundColor;
  color.select();
  document.execCommand("copy"); 
})
```

Console shows error

> Uncaught TypeError: color.select is not a function.

Do you know any other way to get this working?

Comment: From the code it's unclear what you want to achieve. Please explain your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand well, you want to copy background color property to clipboard.
i got help from this link.
https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f

And i tried in jsfiddle, it works fine. I hope this help

```
<div class="color">hello</div>
```

>

```
  const copyToClipboard = str => {
      const el = document.createElement('textarea');
      el.value = str;
      document.body.appendChild(el);
      el.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      document.body.removeChild(el);
    };

    $('.color').click( function () {
      color = $(this).css( "background-color" );
      copyToClipboard(color);
    });
```